# Sublime Text 3 Theme: Some sidebar Icons not rendering

Tags: debugging, themes, sublimetext3

I'm writing a custom theme based on [kkga's Spacegray](https://github.com/kkga/spacegray) theme, and I've run into an issue with the sidebar icons.

These are NOT the file icons feature, but the icons to denote if a folder is open/closed.

It looks like this:

[image: Icons not rendering]

However, when you hover over the rows, the highlighted row's icon renders just fine. Same image, and same path specification - so it's not an issue of the theme being unable to locate the file.

[image]

Can somebody more familiar with ST3 themes point me in the right direction to debug this issue?

ST3 Theme Docs can be found here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I feel really silly. Turns out that the icons that were working, were cached versions (you can find the cache at `/Cache/<package name>` in the ST3 library folder).

I deleted the cache, reloaded the app and found that *all* the icons were not rendering. Realized that I had moved the whole package into the nested `User` directory recently, and as a result the texture paths were no longer correct.

Posting this for posterity. Mods, feel free to close this question.